# vue js modicacion de una varible

Tags: vue.js

Quisiera saber como modifico el valor de un variable,

```
var v_eventosDiv = new Vue({
    el: "#eventosDiv",
    data: {
      variablex:0,
      eventos: []
    }
  });
```

Quisiera saber si puedo modifica la variablex cuando la llame en una condición o algo así.

Answer (score 0):

Depende de dónde quieras modificar esa variable. Por ejemplo si quisieras hacerlo desde fuera del componente:

```
var v_eventosDiv = new Vue(...);

v_eventosDiv.variablex = 1;
```

Si quieres modificarla desde dentro, por ejemplo cuando el componente se monta:

```
var v_eventosDiv = new Vue({
    el: "#eventosDiv",
    data: {
      variablex:0,
      eventos: []
    },
    mounted() {
      this.variablex = 1;
    }
  });
```

El objeto `this` está disponible en las propiedades `computed`, en los `methods`, en el lifecycle (como mounted) y en los watchers. Seguramente en otros lados también, lo cual es muy práctico.

Por ejemplo puedes tener un método que aumente la variable de uno en uno y otro método que fije su valor acorde a un parámetro y `this` sigue ahí, contra viento y marea:

```
var v_eventosDiv = new Vue({
    el: "#eventosDiv",
    data: {
      variablex:0,
      eventos: []
    },
    methods: {
      aumentaX() {
        this.variablex = this.variablex+1;
      },
      setearX(nuevoX) {
        this.variablex = nuevoX;
      }
    }
  });
```

Desde dentro de un template se asume que siempre te refieres al componente, por lo que no usas `this` sino la propiedad sola. Por ejemplo:

```
<div id="eventosDiv">
    <button @click="variablex = 2">Fijar variable x</button>
</div>
```

Lo mismo con los métodos, los llamas directamente:

```
<div id="eventosDiv">
    <button @click="aumentax()">Aumentar variable x</button>
</div>
```